# Is there a way to add submodules to a bare git repository?

Tags: git, gitosis, git-submodules, git-bare

I have some repos on my server with gitosis. One of them is Main, it's including all the others. I work with them from my local machine, and submodules hierarchy was built on my local machine. Gitosis has repos as bare(?) so, it's impossible to include submodules on the server. Problem is, Main repo has a bare clone for Redmine (project management. Redmine shows stats, commits' and files' history. It also lets to write reflinks to commits or files or file's revision straight in wiki). But when files are placed in submodules, redmine cannot access them. So, how to make submodule stats visible in a bare repo?

---

**=== upd ===**

I'm not sure my submodules are always included. Redmine uses a clone of a bare repo and always can show stats for any file, but submodules are shown as files with 0 size. I've already tried default scheme `git@123.456.789.001:Main.git` and now `ssh://git@123.456.789.001/Main.git` submodules are still shown like zero-length files.

`git-status` works fine and shows unpushed commits from submodules, but repos are files, though. This is strange, but redmine now shows commits from submodules but in its own weird way, look at this:

[image: redmine view differences issue with git submodules]

Now I'll try to create a subproject per every submodule, maybe then it will be referencing as it should be. http://www.redmine.org/issues/3169 is totally related.

Answer (score 1):

gitosis (or its more uptodate version [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)) always manage *bare* repos, to allow any user (they authorize) to push to without worrying about a working tree not in sync with the index.

And submodules are always "included" in a bare repo: a submodule is just a reference to the relevant commit (plus an address to the repo of the submodule).

What could trip Redmine is:

- the address (url) specified in the .gitmodules is unknown in the Redmine context.
  For example, it uses gitolite:aRepoName, where gitolite is a ssh shortcut defined in your ~/config file (see [here for an example of config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264262/connecting-to-gitosis-server-through-an-ssh-tunnel)): try using a full ssh uri scheme: ssh://[user@]host[:port][/path], and check that address works both from your workstation, and from the Redmine server.
- the use of some options (like `git status --ignore-submodules=all` or `status.submodulesummary` which is by default to false, preventing status to display a summary of commits for modified submodules): try at least to make sure Redmine is in a git environment where `status.submodulesummary` is set to true.

Comment: Thanks for the .git/config settings! Now i can go further.

Comment: @user685107: excellent. What you need to make sure is that the uri scheme used for your submodules is one that you can use on the Redmine server to clone those submodule repos.

Comment: Didn't understand a bit. URI scheme is set one time and will be used everywhere. I'm also cloning repos only one time. And syncing, both without ssh (by absolute path). How access to repo through Redmine is related to that scheme? Whom can i give ssh key pair? Apache cannot use ssh keys and git user cannot into any directory outside its /var/spool/gitosis, so it cannot perform operation on bare redmine repos. I've tried to include repo from a subproject in redmine but no luck, at least for today. I think i've also mazed up some commits, so i cannot make tests for some time.

Comment: @user685107: I meant: what kind of uri is used by Redmine to access said repo? `http://xxx`? `https://yyy`? `ssh`? You need to know if the process using Git within Redmine is able to access that remote repo address. For ssh access for instance, an ssh key would need to be present in `~/.ssh` (but what is` ~` or '`HOME`' for Redmine?)

Comment: Redmine is running as Apache + mod_passenger. syncing repos is done by root's cron script.

Comment: Cron script runs `cd /var/lib/redmine/repos/Main-bare && git fetch origin && git reset --soft refs/remotes/origin/master 2>/var/log/redmine_bare_sync` and origin url is set to `/var/spool/gitosis/repositories/Main.git`

Comment: @user685107: ok. and root is running that cron job? If yes, its account must have the necessary ssh keys.

Comment: Yes, root had them all the time, and that didn't help redmine to see submodule commits and describe them.

Comment: @user685107: and you have the public and private keys in the `HOME/.ssh` of root?

Comment: Yep. 
This is blah-blah text to make it postabe.